# Add a control to new contacts screen in ios

Tags: ios, xcode, contacts, addressbook

I would like to be able to just add a control to the new contacts screen or override the new contacts screen people see when clicking add contact from the phone answer default screen in the iPhone.

Is it possible that as long as my app is installed I can add to or override the default screen when clicking the + to add a new contact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to alter the behavior in a default Apple app?

The answer is no...you won't be able to do that. Apple does not let third-party apps mess with the core functionality of the phone.